# downloading a pdf into app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, sqlite

i am stuck with an issue,in my app i am creating to download a pdf file from a url and it has to save in my app.can any one give me suggestion how to download the file and store it in the app.

thank you all.

Comment: Have you tried searching for existing answers? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=download+file+iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSData` to retrieve files from the Internet (synchronously):

```
NSURL *downloadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mydomain.tld/myfile.pdf"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:downloadUrl];
[data writeToURL:filePath atomically:YES];
```

To download data without blocking the main thread (asynchronously), view the answer to this post:

[iPhone SDK: How do you download video files to the Document Directory and then play them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572529/iphone-sdk-how-do-you-download-video-files-to-the-document-directory-and-then-pl)

You cannot save any files to your application bundle, but you can save them to an application-specific Documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.pdf"]; 

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```