# downloading pdf and save it into within the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my app, i have to connect with a url and download a pdf file. I tried with [uiapplication sharedapplication:url]; but it is not at all work for me. So can anyone suggest me how to download a pdf and save it in my app??

Thank you all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [downloading a pdf into app..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526313/downloading-a-pdf-into-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A not so great solution, but easy to implement, is to do a synchronous download. For example to download google's root page you could do:

```
NSData *d = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"goog.html"];
[d writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
```

This is not great for two reasons:

1. It stores the file in memory thus will not work for large files
2. It is synchronous thus if you run this in the main thread it will freeze your app while the download occurs

A better solution is to use a NSURLConnection and do an asynchronous download. In your NSURLConnection delegate, create the file when the download begins and append the data in the - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d method. Look into the NSURLConnection, NSFileManager and NSFileHandle classes.

Comment: is that possible to download and save file in a bundle programatically in iphone

Comment: You can't save to the Bundle. The bundle is signed and changing it would make your app to stop working. You should save it to NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); as the code shows.