# Need a tutorial for iOS to play video files in my application

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am going to build an iOS app that will download video from my web services to play offline in the application.

I am looking for a tutorial that will show me the basics which will include:

1. Downloading the video file from the web
2. Storing it in a data store for my application (what structure / location)
3. Playing this video from my data store
4. What video format I require

Comment: Finding a tutorial that does all that you ask (basically writing your application for you) might be a little too specific.  However, this previous question covers the important parts of downloading and playback of video: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572529/iphone-sdk-how-do-you-download-video-files-to-the-document-directory-and-then-pl

Answer (score 8):

Generally I use [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to download things off the web, it is a great library that handles multithreading for you. It should give you a url. You can then play the video using the `MPMoviePlayerController` class. The following is the code to play the video:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

[[player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]]; // Frame must match parent view

[self.view addSubview:[player view]];

[player play];

[player release];
```

Answer (score 2):

To download the video from web, you can use [ASIHTTP framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). There are plenty of examples which will give you a head start.

After that you can follow this tutorial, to playback the stored video - [**Video Playback from within an iOS 4 iPad Application**](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_4_iPad_Application_%28Xcode_4%29)