# Way to go ahead after mpmovieplayercontroller deprecation in iOS9

Tags: ios9

I have a code which does:

```
    self.video = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    self.video.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [[self.video view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.video.view];
    [self.video play];
```

It basically loads a url and starts playing it. With the deprecation of MPMoviePlayerController what is the framework to be used to do the above functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Use below ways provided by Apple. Basically using `AVFoundation` framework, Also it support picture in picture feature to support latest iOS 9 multi tasking feature.

**Apple Documentation**

> The AVKit framework provides the AVPlayerViewController class, which
>   automatically displays a PiP button for your users.
>
> If you support PiP using AVKit but want to opt out of PiP for a particular video, assign
>   a value of NO to the player view controller’s
>   allowsPictureInPicturePlayback property.
>
> AVKit also provides the AVPictureInPictureController class, which you
>   can use with the AVPlayerLayer class from AV Foundation. Use this
>   approach if you’d like to provide your own view controller and custom
>   user interface for video playback.