# iOS 9 MPMoviePlayerController Deprecation

Tags: ios, deprecated

I have an app on the store currently which uses MPMoviePlayerController based Media Player to play Audio/Video. It looks like MPMoviePlayerController and related libraries are being deprecated in iOS 9 (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html)

I do not have access to iOS 9 beta to check this myself, but is it safe to assume that my app will stop working (media playback) on iOS 9? Or does it mean it will still work but *may* lead to uncertain behaviour. Does anyone have any knowledge about this based on their past experience of deprecated APIs on iOS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift

Answer (score 3):

Deprecation doesn't mean that your app will stop working. It means that Apple is gradually phasing out usage of those classes, and that, at some point in the future, they will drop support completely. However, Apple will make it clear when these classes are no longer available.

The classes will still work as expected, but you should switch to using ones that have replaced them.

Comment: I knew that the App will not stop working, what I meant to ask was will media playback work. Going by your comments, I think it is safe to assume it will work but support in future versions is not guaranteed. That is fine for me, because I am planning an update for the App anyway. Thanks.