# MPMoviePlayerController deprecated, what now?

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

So I have been searching for a solution now when MPMoviePlayerController is getting deprecated. my current code works fine:

```
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: receivedURL)
    moviePlayer!.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
    moviePlayer!.view.frame = view.bounds
    moviePlayer!.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill
    moviePlayer!.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
    moviePlayer!.shouldAutoplay = true

    view.addSubview((moviePlayer?.view)!)
    moviePlayer?.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
    moviePlayer!.play()
```

I record a video, and once I'm done recording, it will be played back with the code above in a new view. But as I understand MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated in iOS9 and I can't find any solution working like the code above. I understand I need to user AVPlayer and AVPlayerViewController.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift) and many other solutions that looks like them.
But it just won't work like I want it in the code above.

I just want to record a video, and have it played back in a new view, exactly like snapchat.

Please help me

ADDED ADDITIONAL INFO:

So when I try to fix it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25933122/4545564) (the accepted answer) or [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277658/4545564) (AVPlayer), the view is blank. nothing is shown.

```
var player:AVPlayer!
    let avPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
    player = AVPlayer(URL: receivedURL)
    player.play()
```

And If i try with the [AVPlayerViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277658/4545564) which I had to modify:

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: receivedURL)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    })
```

this happens, where nothing is shown.
[image]

Comment: Your linked answer seems like the solution. Expand on "But it just won't work like I want it in the code above."  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What issues are you running into when you're trying to use `AVPlayerViewController`?  Your question doesn't make sense.  What's "not working?"

Comment: Ok I will edit the question and add a picture :) 
but with the answered I linked, there is two problems 
the first one is that nothing is played, the view is totally blank
the other problem is that a video player is shown but is grey.

I will take print screens and add them with the code

Answer (score 7):

```
var player:AVPlayer!
let avPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:50,y:50,width:100,height:100)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
player = AVPlayer(url: receivedURL)
player.play()
```

here you initialize your player AFTER adding it to AVPlayerLayer. try like this:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: receivedURL)
let avPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:50,y:50,width:100,height:100)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
player.play()
```

Comment: still just an empty view :/

Comment: something may be wrong with your video url. I tried this one - http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4 - and everything works as excpected. remember that if your video url is not https://, you need to configure App Transport Security Policy.

Comment: a dumb question, i should do this in my viewdidload? like:
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlPath: String = "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        let avPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
        player.play()
    }

Comment: yes, it's ok to do this in viewDidLoad. btw i'm sorry, i have forgotten http:// in my link

Comment: no its there, i think its just Stackoverflow removes it when pasted in here.. I did it like the code above in my viewdidload, but still blank.

Comment: do you have any other views on your view? do you have  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>  in your Info.plist?

Comment: I tried in a new project, just file -> new-> project..
and there i tried to paste into viewdidload to see if it works. but not even there

Comment: ok, so if I create a new project, and play the previous recorded video that works with the MPMoviePlayerController in the viewdidload like this:
let urlPath: String = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B98B09BE-8B4C-447E-B60B-E1FDD0179485/tmp/tempMovie.mp4"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        let avPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.frame
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
        player.play()
it works, but not in my previous proj

Comment: it means that smth is wrong with your previous project. look at subviews of your root view carefully, maybe something is convering your player?