# Swift AVPlayer doesn't appear, only sound

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

i have this code for stream a video from my server :

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

class VideoController : UIViewController{

    let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var avPlayer : AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
        playVideo();
    }

    func playVideo(){
        let movieUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string : "http://---------")!;

        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
        self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer

        self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()

        print("CI SIAMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");

    }
}
```

the problem is that i can't see anything but able to hear the audio.
What is the problem? sorry for bad english.

Comment: I can't see anywhere where you add the player to you view. This question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift might provide some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
   First add Your View Controller to MainViewController Like this,

```
 self.presentViewController(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

It Works otherwise try this:

```
  self.avPlayerViewController.player = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
  self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()

   or

  var avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: movieUrl);
  self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(Item:avPlayerItem);
  self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
```