# AVPlayer does not play Video, play Button with Line through

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming

Im new to swift but i like it more than obj-c as it looks a bit like java does to me from syntax wise compared to obj-c.

My problem is now that most of the source code samples are for obj-c so theyre unreadable for me =)

Anyway i managed to run a few code snippets like this(im not at my mac but they were similar):

```
    let steamingURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://....")!
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: steamingURL)
    player.allowsExternalPlayback = false

    PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController.player = player
  self.addChildViewController(PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController.view)
    PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController.view.frame = videoContainerView.frame
    PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    player.play()
```

resulting in a Play Button with a line trough it, it doesnt play the Stream.
The stream source is a mpg1/2 stream according to VLCPlayer and its coming from a Linux based satellite receiver.

Another thing i tried was to change that "string:" part to "fileURLWithPath:" at the NSURL variable but that didnt work either.

Is there a way to Buffer the stream or is this just a codec issue, what workaround options do i have?

Im hesitating since three days, i hope its not a duplicate question, thanks.

EDIT: content of the stream.m3u file:

## EXTM3U

## EXTVLCOPT--http-reconnect=true 192.168.178.20:8001/1:0:1:445D:453:1:C00000:0:0:0:

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25933122/790842

Comment: tried all, works with the embedded "big_buck_bunny.mp4" resource, but streaming from my device does not

EDIT: the code snippets i referred are from that thread =)

Comment: Code is correct it works for me, doubting the url.

Comment: the stream.m3u content:

#EXTM3U
#EXTVLCOPT--http-reconnect=true
http://192.168.178.20:8001/1:0:1:445D:453:1:C00000:0:0:0:

Comment: If it is of any help, i can open the port and redirect the stream outside but i think its not wise to post the IP Address in public O.O

Comment: Read this https://developer.apple.com/streaming/ you will get help.. remove your url.

Comment: the URL i posted is a local one, so no problem so far =)
i also know of that link, if you are about the 10 minute restriction, then i must ask how the IP Camera implementations do work, as far as i know they are also continuous mpg streams

Look what i also found while googleing for that #EXTVCOPT tag
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20114

Answer (score 0):

Security setting might be the problem. Go to info.plist and Add "App Transport Security Settings". Under that add "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and set it to YES. I hope this fixes the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, but for local video files, any idea?