# play live broadcasting news - swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, video, live-streaming

I want to play live broadcasting/streaming video in ios. i am trying using AsyncDisplayKit but video is not playing. is there any library for this?.

```
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async(execute: {

        if self.mainNode == nil {

            self.mainNode = ASDisplayNode()
            self.videoNode = ASVideoNode()
            self.videoNode!.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height)
            self.videoNode!.gravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            self.videoNode!.shouldAutoplay = true
            self.videoNode!.shouldAutorepeat = false
            self.videoNode!.muted = false
            self.videoNode.delegate = self
            self.videoNode.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.videoNode!.placeholderEnabled = true
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.mainNode!.addSubnode(self.videoNode!)
                self.addSubview(self.mainNode!.view)
            })
        }

        self.videoNode?.asset = AVAsset(url: self.url)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
          self.videoNode?.placeholderImage()
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use AsyncDisplayKit here. You can use native AVPlayer or AVPlayerViewController stream video.

For more details: [How to play video with AVPlayerViewController (AVKit) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift)

Comment: It wont plays from url https://bmplayer-a.akamaihd.net/shareable/embedssl.html?dc=cp24_web&cid=982467&col=379&w=960&h=540&pl=0&plh=0&adSite=ctv.cp24&adZone=default&omniAcct=ctvgmtvecp24desktop,ctvgmtvecp24globalsuite&section=CP24&site=cp24&shareUrl=http://www.cp24.com/&v7=home&v8=&v9=&v10=