# Download Audio file from URL and play it in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have an URL which I get from JSON response, When I hit the URL in browser the file is downloaded, Now am wondering how can I play such URL which is a Download URL.I've been looking around many post But none of them could help me.

type of url am getting : http://www.smartivr.in/sounds/voicemail/download/f77245d9-e7ee-4424-850c-6a45022d0a54_1

Below is the code I tried.

```
  NSString *audio=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",cell.url];
  NSLog(@"url:%@",audio);

  NSURL  *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio];
  NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
    [soundData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSError *error;
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
                                                           fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:&error];
    [_audioPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"error %@", error);
```

Comment: You should try streaming the audio file from the url instead. Edit: What @Marek said.

Comment: @Ramon but it is a download url.

Comment: @Shikha Sharma Do you want to play audio from downloaded filePath or from your online url?

Comment: @DipankarDas i just need to play the audio , be it anyway.

Comment: First of all the URL is a remote URL so you have to use the `[NSURL URLWithString...` initializer and generally **do not** load data from a remote URL with a synchronous method like `dataWithContentsOfURL`. Use `URLSession` which works asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    //download your audio file
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.smartivr.in/sounds/voicemail/download/f77245d9-e7ee-4424-850c-6a45022d0a54_1.mp3";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];
    NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
    [soundData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    // get the file from directory
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

    NSURL *soundUrl;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:soundPath])
    {
        soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath isDirectory:NO];
    }

    // play audio file
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
```

You should download your audio file asynchronously.

Comment: but i can't hear it, i applied same code, though volume button is working, otherwise it was not showing. but it's not audible

Comment: :( what could be the reason, that it's not audible in my device

Comment: you can check on your simulator.

Comment: add this [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];  for sound.

Comment: hey i got it's solution

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: check my post , i just posted it

Comment: Do not use the code in this answer to download a remote file. Use `NSURLSession`.

Answer (score 2):

try use AVPlayer or AVPlayerViewController, you can use direct URL to play mp3 files

even with local file as you will first download it to device, then play from local URL

do not forget that object AVPlayer has to be as property of your Class not local object because of auto-releasing, so declare your player variable in class and set in function not just locally in function and try to play ...

[update]

more details how to do it -> [How to play video with AVPlayerViewController (AVKit) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift)

Comment: That's what i wanna know. how to exactly download it and then play. cuz i tried so many methods and none of them worked. I'll be thankful, if you care to provide me some code.

Comment: And where is a problem? you should at least describe what exactly and which step is not working

Comment: i have a mp3 URL which i want to play in avplayer . i have tried every possible way out there but it just dose not play the song . anyone one knows any method of paying song from given url ?

Answer (score 2):

Thank You Dipankar Das for you help.
I am posting the whole solution here.
which worked for me absolutely.

```
    NSString *audio=@"http://www.smartivr.in/sounds/voicemail/download/f77245d9-e7ee-4424-850c-6a45022d0a54_1.mp3";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:audio];
    NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
    [soundData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    // get the file from directory
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

    NSURL *soundUrl;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:soundPath])
    {
        soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath isDirectory:NO];
    }

    // plau audio file
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_audioPlayer play];
    [_audioPlayer setVolume:5.0];
```

Comment: i have a mp3 URL which i want to play in avplayer . i have tried every possible way out there but it just dose not play the song . anyone one knows any method of paying song from given url ?

Comment: Do not use the code in this answer to download a remote file. Use `NSURLSession`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake

```
NSString *audio=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",cell.url];
NSURL  *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio];
```

I assume that it is a remote url and you cannot treat it as a file url. So you must use

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL urlWithString:audio];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;

AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview18/v4/9c/db/54/9cdb54b3-5c52-3063-b1ad-abe42955edb5/mzaf_520282131402737225.plus.aac.p.m4a"]];

    // Create player item
    
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    
[self.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

[self.player play];
```