# xcode: How to Play a video within the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to play a video in my ViewController(not in seperate ViewController).
in another words, i want to play my video in a rectangular View in my viewController. just like instagram posts. but i didn’t found any view in object library for that...!

Comment: Please look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277658/3490203

Comment: thankyou verrrrrry much...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play video with AVPlayerViewController (AVKit) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift)

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

`import AVKit`

`import AVFoundation`

```
class VideoPlayerViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var videoPreviewLayer: UIView!
private var player: AVPlayer!
private var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playVideoInView()
}

func playVideoInView() {
    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("videoName", ofType: "mp4") else {
        return
    }

    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
    player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    playerViewController.view.frame = videoPreviewLayer.frame
    self.addChildViewController(playerViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
}
```

}

`playVideoInView` function has what you need