# How to show Vimeo live video stream in native iOS app

Tags: ios, stream, vimeo, live

Vimeo has released the **live** video stream service. But I cannot find a live stream url in Video settings in Vimeo. I use HLS link to show normal Vimeo stream videos in AVPlayer and that works. Where can I find the url for live stream video on Vimeo? Is it possible to show live stream video on iOS app or must I embed webView to show Vimeo live video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play video with AVPlayerViewController (AVKit) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift)

Comment: This is not a duplication. I asked how to play live video from video. That's different from your link.

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/LXVimeoKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a long time ago since the question was published, but maybe someone can benefit from this.

Vimeo has a tutorial on their site https://developer.vimeo.com/api/live/playback.
How to get the HLS link to the live video.

One major drawback is, to qualify for the Vimeo Live API you must be a Vimeo Enterprise customer or a Vimeo development partner.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: for now, Vimeo Live can only be used with the Vimeo embedded player. Vimeo does not offer an HLS or other external link/streaming link for Live events.

Those [direct file links](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Direct-links-to-video-files) are only available for uploaded complete videos.

Comment: Do you mean we are restricted to the iFrame player and would have to use some sort of webview or is there a way to somehow display this player inside of a `UIView`? Thank you.