# open video URL in IOS native player from any browser

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, stream

in android we have **"intent"** to open any network stream but I am trying to play video in IOS native player I don't know how to open network stream in IOS browser

```
<a href="intent://seach.sigmacdn1.workers.dev/stream/782167627762213921323a534a3273356a2e643b60547460365c675c57625c71614e3a50503361773171212f21776a6e662139323535363a3b31333537373b327e/dcsdcdsc#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;scheme=http;type=video/mp4;end">Intent: Link; will play in app</a>
```

i want to play this url in ios video player

Comment: can you please check this out, hope it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift

Comment: I need in javascript , browser side