# HTTPS request - get document on iOS

Tags: ios, httprequest

I have link to document (e.g.: https://example.com/test/test.pdf). I have tried to use `ASIHTTPRequest`, but it's not working. I know that I can get it by using `NSURL`, but is there another way or framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the content of a document just with NSURL, NSURL is a representation of the url, you must do the request.

Some elements here : [iPhone SDK: How do you download video files to the Document Directory and then play them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572529/iphone-sdk-how-do-you-download-video-files-to-the-document-directory-and-then-p)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use NSURLConnection here. [See documentation on it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do with STHTTPRequest https://github.com/nst/STHTTPRequest

```
__block STHTTPRequest *r = [STHTTPRequest requestWithURLString:@"https://example.com/test/test.pdf"];

r.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *body) {
    NSData *pdfData = r.responseData;
};

r.errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    //
};

[r startAsynchronous];
```