# How to Download a video using UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video, uiwebview

I want to download a the video using web-view but I am not getting how to download it? 
my video link is [here](http://player.vimeo.com/video/32983838)

the sample code for playing video which I am using is

```
-(void)embedYouTubeInWebView:(NSString*)url theWebView:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url];
    [aWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:html]]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
   [self embedYouTubeInWebView:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/32983838" theWebView:myWebView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

can anyone please help me to download this video?

Comment: Youtube has restricted any video downloads from any of the external sources recently. You'll not be allowed to download any you tube video from any software or app. You can only view them in a UIWebView.

Comment: have you check the link?this is not a youtube link

Comment: Yeah I checked it... But it just plays the video right?

Comment: yes i want to download such video but i dont know how?

Comment: I told u its no longer allowed.. I had an app in my android mobile which downloaded youtube videos, but since 10 days. It stopped working.. I searched for that and found that its no longer allowed now.

Comment: Okay.. if u find any source.. plz let me knw...

Comment: First You get me the info about the downloading.. then i'll surely upvote...

Comment: try this So answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572529/iphone-sdk-how-do-you-download-video-files-to-the-document-directory-and-then-p

Answer (score 6):

To download a  file  i used the following Code. Hope it will work for you too.

```
- (IBAction)getFileFromFtpServer:(UIView *)sender
{

  NSString *stringURL = @"http://player.vimeo.com/video/32983838";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.mpeg4"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Try this here your video is playing..

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIWebView*  webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 380)]; 
    webView.delegate=self;
   [webView setOpaque:NO];
    webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screen);
   UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake((width/2) - 10,(height/2) - 54, 20, 20);
    activityIndicator.center=self.view.center;
    [activityIndicator hidesWhenStopped];

   [self  playVideo];
}
  -(void) playVideo
    {
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/32983838"];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [self.webView loadRequest:request];
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];
            [webView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    }

    /*   WebViewDidStartLoad   */
    - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
       [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES]; 
    }

    /*   WebViewDidFinishLoad   */
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
         [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO]; 
    }
    /*   WebViewdidFailLoadWithError   */
    - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO]; 
    }
```

Comment: this is for only playing a video i need to download

Comment: NSString  *VideoPath;NSURL  *urlVideo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/32983838"];NSData*urlVideoData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlVideo]; if(urlVideoData {NSArray*pathVideo=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString  *documentsDirectory = [pathVideo objectAtIndex:0];VideoPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"youtubeVideo"];[urlVideoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];}[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:VideoPath]]];Try this your video will be download

Comment: filePath replace with VideoPath like [urlVideoData writeToFile:VideoPath atomically:YES];

Comment: please give me proper answer i am not getting what you want to say

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and in response to above, google has shut down several "converter sites" due to copyright infringements:  http://www.real.com/resources/youtube-to-mp3-converter   There are other sites available to download video content from (again, assuming you're abiding by the copyright guidelines) :   This lists five sites  where you can find and download online videos free.  To make sure a video is legal to download, look for licensing information about the video. Typically, videos with a “Creative Commons” license are legal to download, but may have limitations on how you use the video.  http://www.real.com/resources/download-one-video