# MPMoviePlayerViewController won't play movie, start and closes immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, mpmoviewcontroller

I'm trying to play a video with MPMoviePlayerViewController, I present the MPMoviePlayerViewController but after 1 second he is dismissing itself.

This is my code:

.h:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController;
```

.m:

```
- (void)playmovie
{
    NSString *databaseName = @"NO.mp4";
    NSArray *documentPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
    self.moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayerViewController];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Please tell me what I did wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check below answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15586468/1713478 change url to your file path. try this you will be succeed.

Comment: What's with the graphics context there?

Comment: @jjv360 because i've got this error: `<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawShading: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0`

Comment: Can you give the code in `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated`?

Comment: @jjv360 What do you mean? When i'm writing only `self.moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayerViewController];` those 2 lines, I have this context error. Don't know why.

Comment: @Pratik I've tried what you've told me to, but still it's not working, but now, it just keeps loading.

Comment: which file format of video are you using?

Comment: mp4. Now i'm using this code:     `NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NO" ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:@""]];
    NSLog(@"\n\nthe string %@",urlString);` and it prints me `null` I don't know why. The files are inside 'Copy Bundle Resources' but still returns null again.

Comment: try below

NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NO" ofType:@"mp4"];
       
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Comment: It's working man, thanks a lot! really! put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: you are always welcome and i wiil put in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check below answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586468/1713478

change url to below code

```
NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NO" ofType:@"mp4"]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

try this you will be succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
NSString *databaseName = @"NO.mp4";
    NSArray *documentPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
    moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
    moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMediaTypeMusicVideo;
    [moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```