# Issue with playing video file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using following code to show video file in initial state.But when i launch app it start playing without giving me option to play.how i can achieve that

```
            NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"En_annan_resa_Master_ENG_PC" ofType:@"mp4"];
            NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
            movie_obj = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
            [movie_obj.view setFrame:CGRectMake(1024*i, 0, 1024, 748)];
            movie_obj.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
            [self.scrollView addSubview:movie_obj.view];
            [movie_obj prepareToPlay];
```

I am expecting when i launch app it show mw video view and show control to play do not play automatically.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15701076/1713478

just replace **NO** to **En_annan_resa_Master_ENG_PC**
try this your problem will solve